Should I use React.createElement to return multiple children from a Component?
I have a component that receives a raw text and some extended information. It enhances the text with this information and returns an array of text snippets and enhanced Components.
Initially, I created a function to do the transformation and return the transformed content, using React.createElement:
const transform = (text, data) => {
  // do the transformation
  // ... 

  // In the end, I have this array consisting of text snippets and Components
  transformedElements = [
    'text',
    <MyLink>Word</MyLink>,
    'more text',
    <MyLink>AnotherWord</MyLink>,
  ];
  return React.createElement('div', null, transformedElements);
}

But then I wrote this as a Component:
const Transformed = ({text, data}) => {
  // do the transformation ...
  transformedElements = [
    'text',
    <MyLink>Word</MyLink>,
    'more text',
    <MyLink>AnotherWord</MyLink>,
  ];
  return transformedElements; 
  // also works as:
  // return React.createElement('div', null, transformedElements);
}

And I realized it would also work if I did return transformedElements directly.
I'm guessing it performs better since it doesn't call createElement, and the only difference I could notice is that the returned components won't be wrapped in a containing element, like in the previous implementation.
So, should I call createElement or just return the array? What are the pros, cons, and drawbacks of each approach, if any?

Returning an array of JSX is still valid JSX. Generally you'd use createElement if you needed to inject some additional props into children components. Since you are not doing that it doesn't really matter much if you use it or not.

1. Return the Array Directly (Recommended)
const Transformed = ({ text, data }) => {
  const transformedElements = [
    'text',
    <MyLink key="word-link">Word</MyLink>,
    'more text',
    <MyLink key="another-word-link">AnotherWord</MyLink>,
  ];

  return transformedElements;  // Just return the array
};

Pros:

Easier and cleaner to write.
Better performance (no extra wrapper).

Cons:

No wrapper element, which may cause layout issues if a container is needed.


2. Use React.createElement() (If you need a wrapper)
const transform = (text, data) => {
  const transformedElements = [
    'text',
    <MyLink key="word-link">Word</MyLink>,
    'more text',
    <MyLink key="another-word-link">AnotherWord</MyLink>,
  ];

  return React.createElement('div', null, transformedElements);  // Creates a div wrapper
};

Pros:

Provides a parent wrapper (like a div), useful for layout control.

Cons:

Adds an unnecessary wrapper if not required.
Slightly more verbose.


Conclusion:

Return the array directly if you don’t need a parent wrapper.
Use createElement if you need a container element.



Either case can render the same output - that is without an additional wrapper of div tag.

The actual difference is in the amount of the code transpiled in each case.


The point is the latter case - React Component, will require an additional step of transipilation since it renders a React component. However this is entirely a technical aspect, a React developer should never be concerned about it.
The recommendation is : React provides a declarative way to manipulate the UI. It means a React developer describes the different visual states the components can be in and switch between them in response to the user inputs. This in general makes the intend clear and takes away the imperative codes deal with implementation details. The essence is that JSX is preferred over invoking createElement calls. Therefore please adhere to components based on JSX - the recommended programming constructs in React, and take the best productivity out of it. For more, request you may please go through the sections Thinking in React, https://react.dev/learn/describing-the-ui and Managing state
Please see below each case with codes, test results and transipled codes.
Case 1 : ordinary function
const transform = (text, data) => {
  const transformedElements = [
    'text',
    <label key={1}>Word</label>,
    'more text',
    <label key={2}>AnotherWord</label>,
  ];
  return transformedElements;
};

export default function App() {
  return React.createElement(transform);
}

Output:

Case 2 : React component
const Transformed = ({ text, data }) => {
  const transformedElements = [
    'text',
    <label key={1}>Word</label>,
    'more text',
    <label key={2}>AnotherWord</label>,
  ];
  return transformedElements;
};

export default function App() {
  return <Transformed />;
}

Output

Please compare the code transpiled in each case. We can see below that there is an additional step in case of the React component.
Case 1 : ordinary function
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = App;
var transform = function transform(text, data) {
  var transformedElements = ['text', React.createElement(
    'label',
    { key: 1 },
    'Word'
  ), 'more text', React.createElement(
    'label',
    { key: 2 },
    'AnotherWord'
  )];
  return transformedElements;
};

function App() {
  return React.createElement(transform);
}

Case 2 : React Component
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = App;
var Transformed = function Transformed(_ref) {
  var text = _ref.text,
      data = _ref.data;

  var transformedElements = ['text', React.createElement(
    'label',
    { key: 1 },
    'Word'
  ), 'more text', React.createElement(
    'label',
    { key: 2 },
    'AnotherWord'
  )];
  return transformedElements;
};

function App() {
  return React.createElement(Transformed, null); // additional transpilation
}

